# inbound and Outbound Gateway AMQP annotation

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, amqp, spring-boot

I have a working spring integration + rabbitmq application using xml config. Now, i am converting them to java config annotation. There are available classes and java annotation for some main amqp objects like `Queue` , `TopicExchange` , and `Binding`. However, I cant find any reference in converting `inbound-gateway` and `outbound-gateway` to java annotation or class implementation.

Here's my implementation:
// gateway.xml

```
<int-amqp:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel" reply-channel="responseChannel" exchange-name="${exchange}" routing-key-expression="${routing}"/>


<int-amqp:inbound-gateway request-channel="inboundRequest"
    queue-names="${queue}" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
    reply-channel="inboundResponse" message-converter="compositeMessageConverter"/>
```

Is it possible to convert them to java annotation or class implementation(bean, etc..)?

ADDITIONAL: I am currently using `spring boot` + `spring integration`.

Comment: In the XML version itself, how do we provide the exchange name ? I want to listen to a queue bound to a topic exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would be great, if you take a look into [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference).

It provides some fluent for AMQP:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow amqpFlow() {
     return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(this.rabbitConnectionFactory, queue()))
           .transform("hello "::concat)
           .transform(String.class, String::toUpperCase)
           .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow amqpOutboundFlow() {
       return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.channel("amqpOutboundInput", this.rabbitConnectionFactory))
               .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(this.amqpTemplate).routingKeyExpression("headers.routingKey"))
               .get();
}
```

From annotation perspective you should configure something like this using classes from Spring Integration directly:

```
@Bean
public AmqpInboundGateway amqpInbound() {
    AmqpInboundGateway gateway = new AmqpInboundGateway(new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(this.rabbitConnectionFactory));
    gateway.setRequestChannel(inboundChanne());
    return gateway;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "amqpOutboundChannel")
public AmqpOutboundEndpoint amqpOutbound() {
    AmqpOutboundEndpoint handler = new AmqpOutboundEndpoint(this.rabbitTemplate);
    handler.setOutputChannel(amqpReplyChannel());
    return handler;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am trying to use these however I dont know where to declar the queue name for InboudGateway. In xml config, you really need to declare the queue-name where the gateway will get the message.

Comment: `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` is responsible for that. The xml tag parser does it for you. That's why I suggets to move to the DSL to avoid such a Java configuration for all bolraplate code, like a container configuration just for `queueName`